# Proof for a limit - Epsilon-delta proof $3x^2 +2x +4$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I am trying to figure out what to do when I get stuck trying to prove an epsilon-delta limit.

For example I saw in the textbook with no answer key like this:
$$
\lim_{x \to 3} \; \bigl( 3x^2 + 2x + 4 \bigr) = 37
$$

I usually will try to isolate $x-3$ from $|f(x) -L|$ but I get stuck with something like $|3x^2 + 2x -33|$
which is less than $|3x^2+2x |$ ( assuming you put some bound on $\delta$). but then I get stuck.
How would you go about solving this?

Comment: Please use MathJax when typing formulae. I did it for you this time. Please check if I interpreted your question correctly. Would $3x^2  + 2x - 33 = (x - 3)(3x + 11)$ help you?

Comment: thanks, if I set d < 1;   and then (x-3)(3x+11) < (x-3) (23)  ( since x<4)
so then x-3 would be less than epsilon if d < epsilon /23

Comment: IMHO it's nonsense to do this using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs. Develop enough theory to show all polynomials on $\Bbb R$ are continuous instead.

Answer (score 1):

With $f(x) = 3x^2 + 2x + 4$ and $L = 37$, you can expand $f(x) - L$ in terms of $x - 3$:
$$
3x^2 + 2x - 33 = 3(x-3)^2 + 20(x-3)
$$
so
\begin{align}
\def\abs#1{\lvert #1 \rvert}
\def\Abs#1{\bigl\lvert #1 \bigr\rvert}
\Abs{3x^2 + 2x - 33} &= 3\Abs{(x-3)^2 + 20(x-3)} \\
&\leq 3\abs{x-3}^2 + 20\abs{x-3} \\
&= \abs{x-3} \, \bigl( 3\abs{x-3} + 20 \bigr). 
\end{align}

In order to make this product small, it suffices to make $\abs{x-3} < 1$ so that
$$
3\abs{x-3} + 20 < 23.
$$
Then, if you also make $\abs{x-3} < \smash{\frac{\varepsilon}{23}}$, you're in business. In other words, given $\varepsilon > 0$, choose
$$
\delta = \min \bigl\{ 1, \tfrac{\varepsilon}{23} \bigr\}.
$$
Now, with $\abs{x-3} < \delta$, you get the estimate
$$
\def\abs#1{\lvert #1 \rvert}
\def\Abs#1{\bigl\lvert #1 \bigr\rvert}
\Abs{f(x) - L} = \abs{x-3} \, \bigl( 3\abs{x-3} + 20 \bigr) 
< \tfrac{\varepsilon}{23} \cdot 23 = \varepsilon. 
$$

Comment: thanks so much, I actually just needed the hint of the factor, not sure why I didn't see that.